# AWS Quicksight if else with dates

Tags: amazon-web-services, if-statement, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to merge two date columns together with the ifelse function, my formula is

`ifelse(RewardPaidDate = null,rewarddate, RewardPaidDate)`

however it only returns the RewardPaidDate column and leaves the nulls in the new calculated field named RewardSentDate. I have tried changing it to

`ifelse(RewardPaidDate = '',rewarddate, RewardPaidDate)`

but I get the error message:
"At least one of the arguments in this function does not have correct type. Correct the expression and choose Create again."

[calculated column is RewardSentDate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxHq8.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewardPaidDate = null
```

is not the correct syntax, you will have to use the [isNull() function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/isNull-function.html) like this

```
ifelse(isNull(RewardPaidDate),rewarddate, RewardPaidDate)
```